# Half-lap joints for day-bed build?

Tags: furniture, design, planning, joints

I'm building a 30"x80" daybed with a simple rectangular structure for the frame. I plan to use 2x6 pine cut to length for the frame. Please do not try to talk me out of the pine, I already have it and know there are better wood options :) The boards on the frame will lay flat and be joined at the four intersections by glued and screwed half-laps. The slats between the boards will be Ikea slats cut to size.

Does my design seem sound? What's the best method for joining the slats to the frame? I plan to order steel legs online for the legs.

[image: Frame plan]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.   Laying the 2x6 boards flat will not span very far without sagging under loads.  How will the frame be supported?  You may want to provide a sketch of your design to get more input. BTW wood glue alone should be more than adequate to secure your lap joint connections.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I was going to use steel legs ordered online. So I'm better off having the boards span the distance upright? Wouldn't that mean less surface area for the contact between the half-joints? (1.5 inches to 1.5 inches)

Comment: *"So I'm better off having the boards span the distance upright?"* Oh yes, much. You're essentially tripling the resistance to sagging by orienting the boards that way (the normal way) compared to using them flat. *"Wouldn't that mean less surface area for the contact between the half-joints?"* You wouldn't then join them using half-laps, you'd choose another option, e.g. internal glue blocks, gussets, bolts that go in the flat of the short ones into the ends of the long ones... or simply go with 'bed bolts' or another fastening system specifically intended for bed construction.

Comment: Was hoping to have a bit more woodworking involved than bed bolts, but it seems like that might be the easiest option. I was hoping to get a look similar to the Herman Miller Nelson Daybed.

Comment: There is no project, large or small, that would not benefit from a quick hand-drawn isometric drawing. Without an image showing dimensions, we'll have a hard time understanding why you are asking what you are asking.

Comment: I updated with a sketchup of the original plan (which would have had slats added to it, possibly glued on for additional support). Perhaps some sort of steel bracketing for extra strength?

Comment: Seeing the new image i would suggest more legs, at least two under middle joints.

Comment: This design is just not taking advantage of the strengths of wood, or trying to alleviate the weaknesses. There is a reason typical simple beds are all variations on a theme, with side-rails for strength. Even 2x6s won't stay flat for very long, even with support in the middle. There is going to be sagging _and_ twisting going on here over time.

Comment: Adding two more legs in the middle would make the span only 42 inches, which according to the sagulator could hold 200 lb/ft with 1.5x5.5 white spruce. I imagine having one of them on each side would increase the load bearing? I don't understand how the sagulator works

Comment: Thanks for the update with the drawing, that makes this much, much clearer. I think if you add feet under the central joints as per @AlaskaMan's updated Answer that the concerns about using the boards flat rather than upright basically go away. Oh one last thing, don't screw the half-laps if you do the joinery right. If you feel you must reinforce those joints then pegging (through-dowels) is IMO aesthetically more pleasing and *less* likely to be a point of failure in the long term.

Comment: P.S. Have you bought the slats yet?

Comment: Excellent! Glad the design has potential with the added legs. How would I do the dowels? My only tools are a hand-operated circular saw, wood chisels, and a random orbital sander. I’m repurposing the slats from an old IKEA bed. The bed is 10+ years old, so I think the slats are made of fairly solid wood.

Comment: I should also note I planned to use one long board for each side. Is that okay or should the long side be split into two boards?

Comment: You didn't @ me so I didn't see that you'd responded. *"My only tools are... "* If those are literally all your tools you'll struggle to do this project to the required accuracy for strength. Simply cutting the lap areas accurately is going to be a struggle. If you can't or won't (no judgement) buy more tools not every one of your joints will end up a little loose, in which case I recommend you glue with epoxy because it is gap-filling. *"I planned to use one long board for each side. Is that okay or should the long side be split into two boards?"* **Definitely** one long board if possible!

Comment: *"How would I do the dowels?"* Just drill holes that the dowels (freshly sanded, lightly, just to refresh their surface) are a good snug fit into, so that they require gentle tapping to seat fully using a mallet or hammer. For even greater additional strength add a dovetail action by angling the dowels slightly. So if two per joint one is angled 5-10° one way, the other in the opposite direction (the angle isn't critical, you can eyeball this every time if you like). You'd need a saw to cut flush/close to flush. And obviously a drill of some sort, and a set of bits.

Comment: @Graphus, thanks for getting back to me! I also have a speed square and some clamps to help with making straight cuts. I’ve been using a thick piece of mdf glued on top of two 2x4s as my cutting surface. I’ve already cut two 10ft boards down to 7ft for my long edges (good to hear using one board per side is the way to go!). I do still need to pick up a drill and saw.

Comment: The dowels sound a little tricky, but I think I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

***An edit with a sketch image was added after i wrote the answer below.
As designed in the sketch i would add legs under the half lap joints in the middle. One leg under each joint**.*

Using 2x6 boards laid flat is not a sound plan. They will be much to flexy and will sag significantly.

Typically a slat bed has a box frame with a cleat on the inside that the slats sit on, they may or may not be secured to the cleat. You will need a center support for the slats that is the same height as the cleat.

You have options for the joinery at the corners, you can use a leg to help strengthen that joint. There are many options and some research will help you decide on something within you abilities.

Many times the slats are connected together with web strapping. Such as [these](https://www.wayfair.com/bed-bath/pdp/alwyn-home-snyder-folding-wood-slats-w001385528.html).

If you do a web search for [slat bed frame](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=diy%20slat%20bed%20frame&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fhomeisd.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F03%2Fbuild-your-own-king-slat-bed-for-150-from-kiwi-an-280489883027120987-e1521822610475.jpg) you find many different ways or designs to accomplish your goal.

Here is an illustration from tutorial on [Ana-White.com](https://www.ana-white.com/woodworking-projects/modern-platform-bed-frame-chunky-legs)

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to get something with more of the look of the Herman Miller Nelson Daybed (https://p1.liveauctioneers.com/429/34732/14244040_1_x.jpg). Does that use a steel frame to avoid the sagging? I can't figure it out. I was hoping for something a bit more modern, but perhaps that is too much to ask for my first project.

Comment: That is interesting. A few thoughts; that span is shorter then a bed frame would be and the wood appears to be a **hardwood like maple**. (*Much stronger then pine*) The inset legs help. How much of that cool design will be visible with mattress on it?  Maybe some angle iron under the flat boards to add support.

Comment: Ah good call, they use white ash or walnut. Twice the bending strength of pine. It's fairly close to my design though. Herman Miller's is 32"x75" and mine is 30"x84". Would I want L brackets for the inside corners? Sorry, I don't know much about working with steel (and would rather not cut into steel myself).

Comment: Wouldn't slats only be required if he is NOT using a box spring.

Comment: I'm not using a box spring. The primary purpose of it is to be sat on like a chaise, but with enough space to sleep on for guests.

Comment: @RyanW, if the primary purpose of this is to be sat on then you need to make the legs longer. Unless the only people intend to use this are children, or very short adults ^_^ Notice how much longer the legs are in the Nelson Daybed, and even those are short by modern standards (bearing in mind that quite a bit of MCM furniture is lower than is really comfortable — it's one area that real-world users confront the *form over function* of mid-century stuff). The single most iconic piece is arguably the Eames Lounge Chair & Ottoman, and it's way low for a lot of people.

Comment: Longer legs can be done! Thanks for all the updates so far :) The sketch probably depicts it poorly, but the end goal is 12” height frame with 6” height cushions for total of 18” seating height (the standard in sofas I think).